# Query Sql to return value

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader

I want to  write Query to display value in MessageBox , but it is not true :

```
SqlDataReader myReader = null;
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select BillNumber from BillData", cn);
cn.Open();
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
MessageBox.Show(myReader.ToString());
cn.Close();
```

Comment: C# or Java? You should choose just one.

Comment: Looks like C#. I have attempted to edit the question to remove Java from the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you just want one return value, you can use `ExecuteScalar()` like this:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select BillNumber from BillData", cn);
cn.Open();
string return_value = myCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
MessageBox.Show(return_value);
cn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do this:

```
myReader.GetString(0);
```

However, there is a bit more that needs done here. You need to leverage the ADO.NET objects properly:

```
var sql = "select BillNumber from BillData";
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    rdr.Read();
    MessageBox.Show(rdr.GetString(0));
}
```

Comment: You need a `rdr.Read()` to load the first row after you execute rdr.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlDataReader myReader = null;
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select BillNumber from BillData", cn);
cn.Open();
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
myReader.Read();
MessageBox.Show(myReader["BillNumber"].ToString());
cn.Close();
```